# Nested Conditional requirements PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, strip-tags

There must be a more efficient way to write this code (below) can someone offer a solution that shows multiple Ifs in a more efficient manner?

```
if (  isset($_POST["submit"])  
   || isset($_POST["submit_x"])
   ) {

    // strip_tags removes tags and then we compare to the original contents
    if (strip_tags($_POST['fld_comments']) !== $_POST['fld_comments']) {

        // Drop post as it had html in it (!==  means Not Identical )
        echo '<h2>No html tags allowed in comments</h2>';
        $blindError = true;  

    } else {

        // run secondary code such to process form

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just strip the tags from the comment and save it? What makes you want to refuse it anyway?

Comment: Indenting (which I have added for you) makes it much more readable, and far easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I had expected that the checking that the page was based on a POST could have been somehow incorporated with the strip_tags checking.

Comment: – jtheman : I could deny the post but would not want to simply strip the tags and then process as the point of the code is to check for bot created spam posts and not allow them to process.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine and efficient. I don't see any problems with it, well, you could use a bit less parentheses, but nothing serious.

I mean:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["submit_x"])) {
```

Comment: Agree. I myself prefer the alternate syntax if(): and endif;

Comment: @jtheman Normally checking posted values and printing HTML would not be at the same place anyways. I also prefer the alternate syntax for HTML, but his code is still fine for what he needs it.